# How to flatten a Flow[T, Seq[Seq[String]], NotUsed] into a Flow[T, Seq[String], NotUsed]

Tags: akka-stream

I have a stream of the type Flow[T, Seq[Seq[String]], NotUsed].

I would like to flatten it in a way that the example stream

```
ev1: Seq(Seq("a", "b"), Seq("n", "m")
ev2: Seq(Seq("x", "y"))
```

should become the following stream:

```
ev1: Seq("a", "b")
ev2: Seq("n", "m")
ev3: Seq("x", "y")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `mapConcat(identity)`:

```
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val events = Vector(
    Vector(Vector(1, 2), Vector(3, 4)),
    Vector(Vector(5, 6))
  )

  Source.apply(events)
    .mapConcat(identity)
    .runForeach(println)

  actorSystem.terminate()
```

prints

```
Vector(1, 2)
Vector(3, 4)
Vector(5, 6)
```

In general, with `mapConcat` you can flatten events-sequences to the main stream.

Comment: But still wondering why this doesn't work with Seq, only with Vector

Comment: @spaudanjo it does not work `scala.Seq`, which is `scala.collection.Seq`, because of type mismatch. `Source.apply` requires its argument to be `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable`, and of course `scala.collection.Seq`, which is not guaranteed to be immutable, is not a subtype of `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable`, while `Vector`, being actually immutable, is. It would also work with `List`, for example; it's just that I usually use `Vector` by default everywhere.